# How do you determine whether a menu item is enabled?

Tags: winapi

A menu item can be enabled or disabled using [EnableMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647636.aspx). How do you determine whether an existing item is enabled?

Comment: you can not use : CheckMenuItem ? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Louis: [CheckMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647619.aspx): *"CheckMenuItem is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. **It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions.**"* Not entirely sure, why you would want to **set** a menu item to test its current state...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether a menu item is enabled is stored as part of a menu item's state information. The following function reports, whether a menu item (identified by ID) is enabled:

```
bool IsMenuItemEnabled( HMENU hMenu, UINT uId ) {
    UINT state = GetMenuState( hMenu, uId, MF_BYCOMMAND );
    return !( state & ( MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED ) );
}
```

A few notes on the implementation:

- A menu item can have both `MF_DISABLED` and `MF_GRAYED` states. A disabled item looks just like an enabled item, but is otherwise inactive. Neither disabled nor grayed items can be selected.<sup>1)</sup>
- The `MF_ENABLED` state equates to 0. As a consequence, it cannot be tested directly, but an expression must be used instead (see [GetMenuState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647982.aspx)).

---

For completeness, here's an implementation using the newer API ([GetMenuItemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980.aspx)). Both implementations are functionally identical:

```
bool IsMenuItemEnabled( HMENU hMenu, UINT uId ) {
    MENUITEMINFO mii = { 0 };
    mii.cbSize = sizeof( mii );
    mii.fMask = MIIM_STATE;
    GetMenuItemInfo( hMenu, uId, FALSE, &mii );
    return !( mii.fState & MFS_DISABLED );
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup>*The distinction between grayed and disabled items is documented under [About Menus: Enabled, Grayed, and Disabled Menu Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553.aspx#_win32_Enabled_Grayed_and_Disabled_Menu_Items). This distinction is no longer exposed in the newer APIs (see [MENUITEMINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578.aspx)), where both `MFS_DISABLED` and `MFS_GRAYED` have the same value.*